# Meu site não fica responsivo é apenas texto

Tags: html, css

Meu site não fica responsivo é apenas texto:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="text_header">I’m Gustavo Marinho,<br> Creative Designer —<br>Product Designer <br>at Netshow.me</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="text_1"> human-centered <strike>design</strike> human<br> I believe we can create change<br> through design.</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="text_2"> My dream is to develop innovative solutions that go beyond the boundaries<br> between art, design and technology to solve problems that impact people's lives.</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Teria como postar o código por completo? As vezes o que pode estar faltando para o site ficar responsivo é a meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Mas só para adiantar, estou vendo que está usando bootstrap, e o correto é você colocar a classe das colunas em uma div serapada, ficando entao: 
`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-12"> 
     //resto do código `

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o que você queira fazer é isto (considerando apenas o trecho apresentado):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <h1 class="text_header">I’m Gustavo Marinho,<br> Creative Designer —<br>Product Designer <br>at Netshow.me</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <h2 class="text_1"> human-centered <strike>design</strike> human<br> I believe we can create change<br> through design.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <h3 class="text_2"> My dream is to develop innovative solutions that go beyond the boundaries<br> between art, design and technology to solve problems that impact people's lives.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Assim ele passará a ter um leiaute dinâmico ocupando os 12 espaços da grade em resoluções pequenas (um por linha), 6 espaços em resoluções médias (dois por linha) e 4 espaços em altas resoluções (três por linha).

Em caso de dúvida, dê uma olhada na documentação sobre o [sistema de grade](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) do Bootstrap, os exemplos são bastante úteis.